# Tensorflow js: Your application contains ops that are small enough to be executed on the CPU backend, however the CPU backend cannot be found

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I use handpose tensorflow model for hand detection in browser using tfjs with webgl backend.
However, i see warning in console
`Your application contains ops that are small enough to be executed on the CPU backend, however the CPU backend cannot be found. Consider importing the CPU backend (@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-cpu) for better performance.`

If i try to add it to my project, I see a lot of warnings about that CPU backend is already registered.

Is there any way to use CPU and GPU (webgl) together in tfjs?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/708) is a thread about it.

Comment: I had this warning too. Now I import both GPU and CPU backend. I still get the warning:  `kernel undefined already registered` but that seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Tensorflow JS does some of the inference (forward propagation as opposed to backprop) on the CPU, since some CPUs have vector arithmetic units that speed up matrix multiplication.

You can check the `tf.ENV.flags` variable to see the various state variables that tfjs sets by default. One of them is the `WEBGL_CPU_FORWARD` flag, which you can set to true like this in the console or in a javascript function.

```
tf.ENV.set("WEBGL_CPU_FORWARD", true)
```

This should activate the CPU backend without you having to import it again in a `script` tag. Or, you can just ignore the warnings since they don't impact your program at all.